# How Do I Find Out Where My Project is Saved?

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that this is a simple question but I am having a problem finding where my project is saved.  I recently updated my Android Studio version and now that I have created a new project I do not know where the project files are being saved.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: right click one of the files/folders in the "project view" and choose "copy path"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And also you can right click on the project and click `show in explorer`,

Edit:
As Matt suggested, you can use copy path also,

Note: 
I am talking about Windows

[image]

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The path to the project is shown in the title bar of the Android Studio IDE window:

[image: Android Studio]

In the above screenshot, the path is shown in square brackets after the application name (`[/tmp/MyApplication]`).

Comment: Also, if you drop down that "Android" menu top left of the project window and choose "Project" instead, you'll see the path right there, and can also right-click on the project and choose, e.g. "Copy Path".

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS with Android Studio 4.2.1 (and possibly earlier) the project path no longer shows in the Android Studio IDE window. I used to get the path from there. Also, there is no "Copy Path" or "Show in Explorer" on MacOS.

However, we can see it when we go to the project view, as you can see in this screenshot below.
[image: project path]